# Is there a way to publish a R flexdashboard html page in SharePoint?; Remove closing

Tags: html, r, sharepoint, browser, flexdashboard

I created a [html](/questions/tagged/html) output from [r](/questions/tagged/r) with `rmarkdown::render(“file.rmd”, “output.html”)`.

The output is a multi-page [flexdashboard](/questions/tagged/flexdashboard) html output with several [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) graphs. There is no shiny involved thus a static HTML file. when I open this file in chrome or edge this file shown exactly as supposed.

I want to integrate this [flexdashboard](/questions/tagged/flexdashboard) html file within [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint). However when I open this file within sharepoint, I only see the title of the [html](/questions/tagged/html) file but all the other parts of the file are not showed correctly. I have tested this on several computers and browsers. Only Edge (not every pc) showed it correctly.

Is there someone who could give advise how to properly integrate an [r](/questions/tagged/r) [flexdashboard](/questions/tagged/flexdashboard) HTML file within SharePoint online?

Comment: If you could provide the sample file code we could play with it to see how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename to aspx file. So `rmarkdown::render(“file.rmd”, “output.aspx”)` will do the trick.